# How do I set a range equal to second to last result in a loop?

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, named-ranges

I have a data list that is almost 92000 lines long.  It contains ICD10 medical diagnostic codes and the code categories titles. The code category titles will always be three characters long (e.g. "A00", "A01", "B00", "B01").  But the three character codes are ONLY category titles when immediately followed by the same code with an appended "0" (e.g "A000", "A010", "B000", "B010").  If the three character code is NOT followed by the appended version, then the three character code is itself a code.

The eventual goal is to provide a data validation list using a listbox residing in a userform.  The listbox must contain ONLY the codes, excluding all the category titles.

My first step is modifying some free code to loop the 92000 lines and build a range that captures all the category titles for exclusion. I've gotten as far as to stop the loop at the detection of the "A00" + "0" instance.  How do I get the result to only highlight the "A00" value and nothing else?

```
Sub HighlightFindValues()

'PURPOSE: Highlight all cells containing a specified values
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim fnd As String, FirstFound As String
Dim FoundCell As Range, rng As Range
Dim myRange As Range, LastCell As Range

'What value do you want to find (must be in string form)?
fnd = "A00"

'Limit test range to 16 lines
Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Validation table").Range("M4:M20")
Set LastCell = myRange.Cells(myRange.Cells.Count)
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(what:=fnd, after:=LastCell)

'Test to see if anything was found
 If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FirstFound = FoundCell.Address
 Else
    GoTo NothingFound
End If

Set rng = FoundCell

    'Loop until cycled through all unique finds
    ‘Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    '----->Change to "Do until FoundCell = result string + 0"
    Do While FoundCell <> fnd & "0"
    'Find next cell with fnd value
        Set FoundCell = myRange.FindNext(after:=FoundCell)


    'Add found cell to rng range variable
    '----->Change rng value to just the 1st result found
        'Set rng = Union(rng, FoundCell)
    'Test to see if cycled through to first found cell
    If FoundCell.Address = FirstFound Then Exit Do

Loop

'Highlight Found cells yellow
rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NothingFound:
MsgBox "No values were found in this worksheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to get an exact match? eg: search for "A001" will not match "A0010"?

Answer (score 1):

If the value you are searching for is the entire contents of the cell then you can modify your initial find call to match the entire cell.

```
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=LastCell)
```

Becomes

```
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=LastCell, LookAt:xlWhole)
```

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the match is performed against the whole value of the cell, need to set the `LookAt` parameter of the `Range.Find` as `xlWhole`.

Additionally as some settings of the `Range.Find` Method are saved each time it is used, it’s a good practice to always set these arguments explicitly *(see [Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746(v=office.15).aspx))*

To correct replace this line:

```
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=LastCell)
```

with these:

```
Set FoundCell = myRange.Find(What:=fnd, After:=LastCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but aren't you just acquiring any cell with text that is only 3 characters in length?

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4:M20")
For Each cell In myRange.Cells
    If Len(cell.Text) = 3 Then
        UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem cell.Text
    End If
Next
```

Updated:

So are you saying take the code if the first word is only 3 characters long? If the first word is always separated by a space, then may be the following would work for you:

```
Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim ICDCode as String

Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M4:M20")
For Each cell In myRange.Cells
    If Len(cell.Text) > 0 Then
        ICDCode = Split(cell.Text, " ")(0)
        If Len(ICDCode) = 3 Then
            ICDCode = ICDCode & "0"
            UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem ICDCode
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Not quite.  First I need to find the cell with only 3 character's length ("A00").  Then continue the find command.  If it finds a value of ("A000") after ("A00") then take the value of of ("A00") and store it in a variable or an array.  

When this is working, I'm going to iterate the loop to find "A01"=>"A010", "A02"=>"A020"..."Z00"=>"Z000".

It's far more likely that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Ah ok, then maybe my updated code would work for you?